# Word segmentation histogram explanation

Tags: image-processing, text-segmentation, handwriting-recognition

I am trying to segment words in a handwritten text line. I am doing this based on a research paper whose word segmentation part is given in the image. I do not understand the quantities for which the histogram is to be made.[Histogram for word segmentation-(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND9ot.jpg)

Comment: ok my virus protection blocks this site you might as well scan this page

Comment: @gpasch I've added an image link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper is written is some "easy-go" fashion.

But lets try to understand.

V() is not a histogram but a filtering mechanism: you work down the line on each column and find the average. I assume the image I(i, j) is binary/black-white (or maybe gray-scale).

```
V(i)=Sum_j I(i, j)/height
```

is the average of image intensities on column i.

So you just calculate these V(i) for i=0, .., width-1.

Then you go from there.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was confused about the double summation.